# Measuring curve “closeness” with unequal data ranges

Tags: classification, curve-fitting

Provided that I have a similar example: [image]

where the blue data is my calculated/measured data and my red data is the given groundtruth data. The task is to get the similarity/closeness between the data and each of the given curves so that a classification can be done, it could also be possible to choose multiple classes if the results seem to be very close.

I can divide the problem in my mind to several subproblems:

- The data range is no the same
- The resolution of the calculated/measured data is higher than the ground-truth data
- The calculated data has some bias/shift

The following questions come to my mind when trying to solve those problems

1. Is it better to fit the calculated/measured data first then attempting to solve the problem?
2. Would it be fine to use the data points as is and calculate the mean squared error of each curve assuming it is a fitting attempt and thus getting the best fit? What would be the effect of the bias/shift in this case?
3. What is a good approach to dealing with the data/range mismatch, by decreasing the number of samples for the higher sampled version or increasing the number of samples for the lower sampled data in the given range?